# How to access a domain or its subdomain from the Local Area Network in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ip, local-area-network

I've got a local server configured with Nginx, PHP5-FPM, MySQL and some other stuff. **I'm hosting two sites**.

- One static website using Twitter Bootstrap and a theme: at
  www.example.com
- One WordPress blog: at blog.example.com

I know I can do the same with just a WordPress site, but the question is other. I can access the two websites from the outside (with my smartphone and my data connection, for example), but the server **has (obviously) a unique IP address**, and when I enter an `http://192.168.1.50` (for example), it shows the first site I created, the static one.

I must disable that one in Nginx (deleting the dynamic link at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/) and restarting the Nginx server **to be able to access the second one** (but only that one) from inside my LAN, and the same happens if I want to access back the first site.

Is there anyway to be able **to access both sites from within my LAN?**

Comment: Why don't you just access the sites by name?

Comment: Within the network? You mean editing /etc/hosts to "deceive" my local machine?

Comment: Yes, either by editing /etc/hosts or installing your own DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is actually to **edit your local machine's hosts file** (OS X, Windows and Linux have it in different locations) file to redirect those DNS to the local IP. In my case

```
192.168.1.50 example.com
192.168.1.50 www.example.com
192.168.1.50 blog.example.com
```

After saving that changes, you can accesss that URLs in your LAN without problems. Thanks for the suggestions, Michael Hampton/Tero Kilkanen ;)